# Should I return null or do nothing?

Tags: php

In PHP, the following yields the same result:

```
function bla1() {
    return null;
}

function bla2() {
    // nothing happening here...
}
```

So if I do this:

```
$bla1 = bla1();
$bla2 = bla2();
```

In both cases the value of bla1 and bla2 is in fact NULL. So my question is, which is best practice? Bla1 is more code, but makes it more obvious what you are doing. But bla2 is less code and yields the same result. Which is better?

Comment: The clearer your code is, the less likely someone will kill you over it

Comment: I prefer to be explicit. `return null;` At least it shows you finished typing the method out and didn't go to lunch halfway through. Of course, seeing the real code might reveal other issues and maybe there's no need for it at all.

Comment: I don't like when nothing happens. Let your functions have a clear single task with a clear response. Avoid the `void`!

Comment: I dont think that one single return statement would affect the performance. Return just belongs to a function. So i would add it. Even better: Return true or false so you might be able to react if the functions fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the function is meant to return something, for example: either an object if it exists, or `null` if it doesn't, then make it explicit by returning `null`.

If the function is not meant to return something, then don't make it return `null`. You can have a single `return` statement on its own if you need to exit the function early.

Answer (score 2):

In most software development projects , the 20-80 rules applies . You will spend 20% of the time on developing your software and 80% of the time maintaining the software. With this rule in mind , **Code Readability** becomes so important in helping you and your colleagues maintain the software .

If you choose

```
function bla2() //not advisable

{
    // nothing happening here...
}
```

You will plant doubts into the mind of colleagues of what is the actual function of the code when they review the code at a later date

**I would be explict and choose**

```
function bla1() //advisable
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the function is tend to return data, then return data or `null` when there is nothing to return. If the function doesn't meant to return any data back, then return `true` or `false` depends on if the function was executed successfully or not.